# Running a method name from string with arguments

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a simple fight method in a small game that handles everything when a user is in a fight. What I'm trying to do is to randomly choose an enemy, by using a random number then assigning the variable `enemy` a name as a String:

```
public static void Fight(String enemy) {
    //code
}
```

The enemys are in a differnet class as individual methods. I'd like to be able to run the enemy methods from my Fight method.

Most of the time the enemy methods will simply return a value, so I would need to be able to add arguments when running the methods.

I was able to find a solution to getting a class and method from a string:

```
try {
    tempClass = Class.forName("com.package.Monsters");
    tempMethod = tempClass.getDeclaredMethod(enemy, null);
    //obj = tempMethod.invoke(Class.forName("com.package.Monsters"), null);

    obj = tempMethod.invoke(tempClass, null);
    enemyStats = (String)obj;

}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This is what I currently have in my Monsters.java:

```
public class Monsters {
    static int[] stats = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    public static String Goblin() {


            //[Health, Attack, Defense, Attack Speed, Movement Speed]
            stats[0] = 6;
            stats[1] = 2;
            stats[2] = 2;
            stats[3] = 3;
            stats[4] = 4;
            String statText = "Health: " + stats[0] + "\nAttack: " + stats[1] + "\nDefence: " + stats[2]
                    + "\nAttack Speed: " + stats[3] + "\nMovement Speed: " + stats[4];
            return statText;
    }
}
```

Currently I call `Fight("Goblin");` to test it. But I'd like to just run the random method at the beginning of `Fight()`, so it might not need arguments itself, if I could use a return value instead.

I couldn't find any way to add arguments to the method for the enemy the `Goblin()`.

I'd like it to be `Goblin(String options)` but I wasn't able to get the `tempMethod` variable to 'find' the method, it gave me the error: "`java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.package.Monsters.Goblin(String options)()`"

Using JDK 19

Comment: Ideally you would make classes here (e.g. a `public class Goblin extends Enemy`), such that you could use different objects for different fights. Then things like `Enemy#getHealth` would allow you to work on something other than strings. For beginners, it's best to avoid `static` for most purposes. Your "found solution" uses reflection which means it is slow and prone to breaking when you change your code. For instance, `#invoke` expects an instance argument, but `null` for static methods.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the reflection? ... Reflection should be the last resort

and please post your complete code as text (formatted!), not as screenshots

Comment: I'm not very experienced with Java, and that was the only thing I found. Optimaly I wouldn't use it because I don't understand how it works. @Rogue What can I look up to find out more about what you wrote?

Comment: I would [start here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html) (particularly the first section regarding object-oriented concepts). From there it'd be a trope down the path of learning more fine-grained OOP topics, e.g. design patterns.